# How to prevent Twig Syntax Error when a plugin is disabled?

Tags: templating, plugins, config, conditional, plugin-sprig

I am using the [Sprig plugin](https://putyourlightson.com/plugins/sprig), and for some reason I'm disabling it in some environments.

In `config/general.php` I have added: `'disabledPlugins' => ['sprig']`

And in my twig template, I have a condition like the following:

```
{% if craft.app.plugins.isPluginInstalled('sprig') and craft.app.plugins.isPluginEnabled('sprig')) %}
    {{ sprig('template') }}
{% endif %}
```

However, even if the condition is `false`, I get this error:

```
Twig Syntax Error – Twig\Error\SyntaxError
Unknown "sprig" function.
```

The same happen if I dump and die before `{{ sprig('template') }}`, so even if the condition is not completed. The same happen if I dump and die before the condition, while the function is not used somewhere else.

[image: Screenshot of error]

How to make the condition working to prevent `Twig Syntax Error` within an invalidated condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this, so I'm actually not sure whether it would work...

What if you moved the `{{ sprig('template') }}` line to a separate included template?

```
{% if craft.app.plugins.isPluginEnabled('sprig')) %}
    {% include 'template/using/sprig' %}
{% endif %}
```

In theory, the Sprig line would never need to be parsed if the Twig include were never called.

---

Side note, you don't need to check both `isPluginInstalled` and `isPluginEnabled` separately. Both checks will be done by the `isPluginEnabled` function.

Answer (score 1):

> The same happen if I dump and die before {{ sprig('template') }}, so even if the condition is not completed. The same happen if I dump and die before the condition, while the function is not used somewhere else.

This can only mean that a `sprig()` call is being executed elsewhere in your templates. You should search your entire `templates` directory (and the codebase of any custom modules/plugins) for `sprig`. Also, be sure to clear the cache to ensure that compiled templates are cleared out before retesting.

Comment: I don't have any other sprig function in any of my others templates. The only other one I have is `{{ sprig.script }}` which if wrapped inside a `craft.app.plugins.isPluginEnabled('sprig')` condition. In my module, I don't have any reference to sprig, just the `Craft::$app->plugins->isPluginEnabled('sprig')` condition. I have updated my question with a screenshot of the error in context.

Comment: I think the error is happening _when Twig is parsed to PHP_... not when that PHP is actually being executed. So in Romain's original example, Twig would still be trying to parse the `sprig()` function into its PHP equivalent (regardless of whether it will be hit when the PHP executes).

Comment: Good catch, Lindsey!